# calling video from wordpress gallery

Tags: javascript, wordpress, video, jwplayer6

I have created thumbnails to load videos from the custom gallery, the link is using javascript like so.

```
<img src="#" onclick="jwplayer().load({file:'http://christiantvonline.net/streams/HTVG_2.mp4'}); jwplayer().play();" />
```

If you click on [the first thumbnail](http://www.christiantvonline.net/0711c/) in this page you will see the video attempts to load and then dies.

Can anyone help with this please, or better way to achieve this, the player is Jwplayer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with the structure/integrity of the code on the page you have linked to, however the answer to the specific question is as follows:

When providing an anchor value (#) as the HREF attribute in an A tag (*you are not using the IMG tag as suggested, otherwise it would work!*), the page will commonly reload - depending on the browser, at least the first time.

As a result, if you are intending on using JavaScript to perform an action and don't want the default link action to occur, you need to stop it as part of your JavaScript instructions:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

So the basic code would look something like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); jwplayer().load({file:'http://christiantvonline.net/streams/HTVG_2.mp4'}); jwplayer().play();">
    <img src="url-to-image.jpg">
</a>
```

Alternatively, you could add the "onclick" attribute to the image (*as you've suggested it was*) and remove the A tag wrapping the IMG.

Your CSS is already applying rollover effects on the image element (not the A tag) and so you may simple need to add the following to make it look like a link:

```
cursor:pointer;
```